# iOS - Capture video simultaneously from both front and rear camera on iphone-6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to develop an iOS app to capture video from both front and rear camera simultaneously on IPhone 6. In so many answers I found that it is not possible in older releases of iPhone.

So I want to clarify that is it possible in the iPhone-6. If it is possible then there is any frameworks that helps to do this?

If anyone have an idea about this problem? please help me !!

Comment: Sorry, but you're asking for "frameworks" to help you and "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Sounds a bit harsh in this case (re above comment on frameworks) as there is only one that does it properly - AVFoundation.  But I agree with first comment - it is not allowed by the hardware unfortunately.  Too much data to write at the same time, when you think of all the video and audio from two streams both doing quite high resolutions.